# Os/exec elegant, loop compatible stdin and stdout input/output

Tags: go, terminal

Example script is just wrapper to "wc -m" command, simple symbol counter.
I trying just feed input with "teststrings" slice elements. And receive number of symbol of each string at output listener goroutine. Looking for a way to make "wc" listen forever for input at all. I'v notice when i increase sleep to

```
time.Sleep(6000 * time.Nanosecond)
```

wc don't wait for input.

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "os/exec"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    BashCommand := exec.Command("wc", "-m")
    InputBytes := &bytes.Buffer{}
    OutputBytes := &bytes.Buffer{}
    BashCommand.Stdin = InputBytes
    BashCommand.Stdout = OutputBytes
    e := BashCommand.Start()
    time.Sleep(1 * time.Nanosecond)
    _, _ = InputBytes.Write([]byte("13symbolsting"))
    if e != nil {
        fmt.Println(e)
    }
    fmt.Println("after run")

    teststrings := []string{
        "one",
        "twoo",
        "threeeee",
    }
    for _, s := range teststrings {
        _, _ = InputBytes.Write([]byte(s))

    }

    //result printer
    go func() {
        for {
            line, _ := OutputBytes.ReadString('\n')
            if line != "" {
                fmt.Println(line)
            }
        }
    }()
    var input string
    fmt.Scanln(&input) //dont exit until keypress

}
```

Comment: You want to use `StdinPipe` on the `Cmd`, not a buffer, but why not just count characters directly in go?

Comment: @JimB this is simple alternative i actually use another command. As far as I understand `StdinPipe` exits immediately after execution. Is there any way to keep pipe opened, while looping?

Comment: What do you mean "exits immediately"? A pipe is open until you close it. (it's an `io.WriteCloser`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you increase the sleep to a large value, the goroutine started by the command to pump `InputBytes` to the process runs before data is written to `InputBytes`.  The goroutine closes the pipe to the child and exits without having read any data.

Use pipes instead of bytes.Buffer:

```
c := exec.Command("wc", "-m")
w, _ := c.StdinPipe()
r, _ := c.StdoutPipe()
if err := c.Start(); err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

w.Write([]byte("13symbolsting"))
teststrings := []string{
    "one",
    "twoo",
    "threeeee",
}
for _, s := range teststrings {
    w.Write([]byte(s))

}
w.Close() // Close pipe to indicate input is done.

var wg sync.WaitGroup
wg.Add(1)

go func() {
    s := bufio.NewScanner(r)
    for s.Scan() {
        fmt.Println(s.Text())
    }
    wg.Done()
}()

wg.Wait()
```

Another option is to write to the bytes.Buffer before starting the command and wait for command to complete before reading the output:

```
c := exec.Command("wc", "-m")
var w, r bytes.Buffer
c.Stdin = &w
c.Stdout = &r

// Write data before starting command.

w.Write([]byte("13symbolsting"))
teststrings := []string{
    "one",
    "twoo",
    "threeeee",
}
for _, s := range teststrings {
    w.Write([]byte(s))

}

if err := c.Start(); err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

// Wait for command to complete before reading data.

if err := c.Wait(); err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

s := bufio.NewScanner(&r)
for s.Scan() {
    fmt.Println(s.Text())
}
```

Comment: Not exatly what i need, Assuming output like
`13
3
4
8`
Anyway thanks for idea.

Comment: @Y01rY5Ogfl The wc command reads standard input to the end and writes a single count.  There is no option for the command to write counts as it's reading standard input.